# When to use a proper API and when to use session state?

Tags: api, api-design, web-api

I was looking at this documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

it is quite long and I asked myself, why would one use this, over just a normal login where you store necessary information in the session?

E.g. when to use proper API, and when to just use web form login in a normal way?

Comment: someone mind to explain whats wrong with the question?

Comment: A "proper API" would allow you to share the same authentication mechanism between your web application and, say, microservices.

Comment: The linked APIs support OAuth authentication, so it seems like the question is less about API vs session state than about the uses/advantages of using OAuth. The main advantage of OAuth being that a user can authorise a third-party application to access data from their account without their actual password ever passing through that application.

Comment: @SeanBurton put it as answer please, now makes sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked APIs support OAuth authentication, so it seems like the question is less about API vs session state than about the uses/advantages of using OAuth. The main advantage of OAuth being that a user can authorise a third-party application to access data from their account without their actual password ever passing through that application.